# Delete file if fail during transaction, how to recover/rollback query execute before

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

Delete file if fail during transaction, how to recover/rollback query execute before?

I need to delete files in transaction, is it possible to know if unlink file fail then means delete file fail then rollback the sql execute before..

**and other question if execute query failed after unlink() how to recover file delete before?**
like make unlink() apart of transaction

```
try{
  $connect_db->beginTransaction();
  // execute select query
  // execute delete query
  // .. execute other query    

  if (is_file($file_path)) {
      if(unlink($file_path) == false) {
          // How to recover/rollback delete query and other query execute before

          $message = '';
          return $message;
          exit;
      }
  }

  //  ....execute other query
  $connect_db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $message = '';
}

return $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
if( is_file($file_path) ) {
      if( ! unlink($file_path) ) { // or if(unlink($file_path) == false) {
          $connect_db->rollBack();

          $message = '';
          return $message;
          exit;
      }
  }
```

As long as your DB supports transaction.

You might want to [read the transaction documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php).

Comment: Thanks for reply! what if execute query failed after unlink()  how to recover file delete before?

Comment: Are you asking if `unlink()` can be part of the transaction?

Comment: It's not going to be part of the PDO transaction.

Comment: ?? usually people how to do it? what should i do to make it work?

Comment: What does the file contain?